# Keycloak & angular - after logging into keycloak I am redirected to a blank page

Tags: angular, authentication, redirect, keycloak

i am having trouble with keycloak and angular, in a nutshell, after logging in with keycloak to being redirected to a blank page.
To be able to leave this blank page I have to refresh the page and I sell it redirected to my localhost.
I am using angular 14.2.6 and keycloak 19.0.1.
When I am redirected the login remains, but it does not show me the information and the button to login remains active.

this is login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { KeycloakProfile, KeycloakRoles } from 'keycloak-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})



export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
  user = '';
  public loggato= false;

  
  
  
  public pu: KeycloakProfile | null= null;


  constructor(private KeycloakService:KeycloakService){}

 /** ngOnInit(): void{
    this.initializeUserOption();
  }
  */ 

  private initializeUserOption(): void {
    this.user =this.KeycloakService.getUsername();
  }
  

 
public async ngOnInit() {
    this.loggato= await this.KeycloakService.isLoggedIn();
    type ruolo=Array<{id:number,text: string}>;
    this.initializeUserOption();
    if(this.loggato){
      this.pu=await this.KeycloakService.loadUserProfile();
      
    }
  }
    

  public lon(){
    this.KeycloakService.login();
  }

  public lout(){
    this.KeycloakService.logout('http://localhost:4200/home');
  }


  
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthConfigModule } from './auth/auth-config.module';
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { initializeKeycloak } from '../app/utility/app.init';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthConfigModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.init.ts

```
import { KeycloakService } from "keycloak-angular";

export function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<boolean> {
    return () =>
      keycloak.init({
        config: {
          url: 'http://localhost:8180/auth',
          realm: 'psw',
          clientId: 'login-app'
        },
        initOptions: {
  
  
      },
      loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true
  
      });
  }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';



const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'login',component: LoginComponent },
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: '**',redirectTo:'', pathMatch:'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

login.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>



<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


<button type="button" (click)="lon()">log</button>
<button  type="button" (click)="lout()">logOff</button>
<p> ciao {{user}}</p>
```

EDIT 1:
In the debug console, when i try the login, give me this error:

```
ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: User not logged in or user profile was not loaded.
getUsername@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:118767:13
initializeUserOption@http://localhost:4200/main.js:909:38
ngOnInit/<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:918:13
asyncGeneratorStep@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120741:24
_next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120763:27
invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8177:158
onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76329:25
invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8177:46
run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7918:35
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9262:28
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8210:171
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76317:25
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8210:54
runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7971:37
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8419:23
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8305:11
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9729:12
globalCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9766:31
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9801:12
EventListener.handleEvent*customScheduleGlobal@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9912:37
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8198:16
onScheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8098:61
```